# Where does NSUserDefaults store the information?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsuserdefaults

Does anyone know where/how does NSUserDefaults store the information for persistence?
I'm just curious about how this works under the hood.

Also I'm wondering if I can manually reset it, but thats secondary..

Comment: It gets stored in your application's sandbox in the `Library/Preferences` folder, with the name `your.bundle.identifier.plist`. You might be able to delete this file to reset them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Userdefaults are persisted at (Simulator 5.0)

```
Users/username/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/your app unique id/Library/com.appname
```

This data is persisted as plist format.

Comment: Yup. Works with simulator 4.2 as well.